# How should I simplify this expression using the Laws of Logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this expression here that I have attempted to solve, but as of now I have no success in solving. My problem is probably the distributing part because I don't know how to continue after distributing.

Question to simplify:

$$(b \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge \neg c) \vee (a \wedge \neg b \wedge c) $$

The answer is :

$$ a \vee (b \wedge c)$$

Can someone help me jump start this problem so I can see how the first few steps are down? I am just unsure how to start this question off >.<'.

I am a slow visual learner so a wall of text won't help me understand much either. Thank you.

Edit:

I have tried distributing and simplifying the 
$$(b \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge \neg c) $$

and I got this $$ ((b \wedge c)  \vee a) \wedge (b \vee \neg c) \wedge (c \vee \neg c)$$

Comment: I think I have something to learn here. Can I know what are the laws of logic. You can even provide a link for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to remove the logical redundancy in the original expression, by grouping similar terms. The distributive properties will be very helpful:

$$ x \wedge (y \vee z) \equiv (x \wedge y) \vee (x \wedge z)$$

$$ x \vee (y \wedge z) \equiv (x \vee y) \wedge (x \vee z)$$

As well as as the law of excluded middle:

$$ x \vee \neg x \equiv T,$$

where $T$ stands for tautology.

Comment: For the first distribution, I had distributed the ( b & c) v (a & ~c) but it got me no where. I am aware of the distribution law, but not sure how to use it when there's some many variables.

Comment: Like I said, first group like terms. Try to simplify first, and expand (complicate) only when it seems the right thing to do. For example if you consider the term $ (a\wedge \neg c) \vee (a \wedge \neg b \wedge c)$, you can factor out $ a \wedge$ using the first distributive property. You get: $a \wedge ( \neg c \vee (\neg b \wedge c))$. Now look inside the first bracket. There's a $c$ and a $\neg c$ in there, so maybe we should distribute $\neg c \vee$ to get it $c$ and $\neg c$ to cancel. We get: $a \wedge ((\neg c \vee \neg b) \wedge (\neg c \vee c))$.

Comment: Then $\neg c \vee c \equiv T$ and $(\neg c \vee \neg b) \wedge T \equiv \neg c \vee \neg b$. So the expression we started with becomes $a \wedge (\neg c \vee \neg b)$. Now plug this back into the original expression and continue.

Comment: You will get $(b \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge (\neg c \vee \neg b))$. Now notice $b \wedge c$ is the negation of $\neg c \vee \neg b$. So now distribute $(b \wedge c)\vee$ and proceed as before, you should get the answer quickly from there.

Comment: I will compare what u said just now to my work, I might just end up uploading a pic of the work I have done.

Comment: ahhh....when we expand the (b∧c) v in we get ((b∧c)∨ a) ∧  (b∧c) ∨ (¬c∨¬b).  At that part I was confused, but I assume we can take the negation out and get ¬(b∧c) with the commutative law as well. Then we get a T.

Comment: I think my problem with these questions is that I am only used to doing examples that look like the laws of logic. SO questions like these that are more abstract aren't as obvious to me. Such as not being able to see the obvious a^ that was able to be factored out >.>..

Comment: It takes some practice. Once you're comfortable manipulating expressions you start to think ahead and notice the patterns more.

Answer (score 0):

$$(b \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge \neg c) \vee (a \wedge \neg b \wedge c) $$

$$\equiv (b \wedge c) \vee (a \wedge \neg c) \vee (a \wedge \neg (b \vee \neg c))$$

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge (b \vee \neg c) \wedge (c \vee \neg c) \vee (a \wedge \neg (b \vee \neg c))$$

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge (b \vee \neg c) \wedge T \vee (a \wedge \neg (b \vee \neg c))$$

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge (b \vee \neg c) \vee (a \wedge \neg (b \vee \neg c))$$

set $(b \vee \neg c) = k$ then

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge k \vee (a \wedge \neg k)$$

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge (k \vee a) \wedge(k \vee\neg k)$$

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge (k \vee a) \wedge T$$

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge (k \vee a)$$

$$\equiv [(b \wedge c)  \vee a] \wedge [(b \vee \neg c) \vee a]$$

from here is easy to follow the result...